# Error 0x80070091 on WSL (windows subsystem for linux) install on Win10

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I first installed WSL on win10 then did an uninstall via the command: lxrun /uninstall / full

I then try to reinstall with lxrun /install

But I'm getting the Error 0x80070091 -- I'm not sure how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was getting that error and after reading Richard Turner's reply, I manually deleted the lxss folder from the C:\Users\bijay\AppData\Local\lxss location
After that the installation started.

Hope this helps
CHeers!!!

Answer (score 10):

As per [BashOnWindows Bug 1902](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1902), this indicates that the %localappdata%\lxss was not empty (or open in another process) and could not be removed.

It's possible that you had a Bash shell open and that a Linux process had a file/folder held open, preventing the lxss folder from being removed). Be sure to close all Bash instances before uninstalling your instance.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Error 0x80070091 has to do with drive corruption. I actually had a truecrypt image mounted that was corrupt that was causing the issue. All I did was dismount and then try to install again and it went through.

So if your getting an error like this make sure none of your drives have corrupting. Possibly do a chkdsk on them.

Comment: "Comment below if you were able to solve this issue a different way. Mine was because of a mounted corrupt drive." - is better served as a comment to your answer, it does not really, belong in the body of your answer.